# Generalization of code is slower than particular case

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, timing

I wrote the following Mathematica module:

```
QNlalternative[NN_, l_, f_] := Module[{s, wz, w, z, j, lvec},
   s = 0;
   Do[
      wz = Table[weightsNodesQ1l@lvec@i, {i, NN}];
      w = Table[wz[[i]][[1, All]], {i, NN}];
      z = Table[wz[[i]][[2, All]], {i, NN}];
      s = s + Function[Sum[(f @@ (Table[z[[i]][[j[i]]], {i, NN}]))*(Times @@ (Table[
                w[[i]][[j[i]]], {i, NN}])), ##]] @@ 
                Table[{j[k], 2^lvec[k] + 1}, {k, NN}],
      ##
      ] & @@ Table[{lvec[i], l + NN - 1 - Total@Table[lvec[k], {k, i - 1}]}, {i, NN}];
   Return[s]
   ];
```

This module calls another module:

```
sumPrime[v_List] := First[v]/2 + Total[Delete[v, 1]]

weightsNodes[NN_] := Module[{w, z},
   w = Table[4/NN*sumPrime[Table[1/(1 - n^2)*Cos[n*k*Pi/NN], {n, 0., NN, 2}]], {k, 0., NN}];
   z = Table[Cos[k*Pi/NN], {k, 0., NN}];
   Return[{w, z}]
   ];

weightsNodesQ1l[l_] := weightsNodes[2^l]
```

This code is related to a mathematical problem I am solving (it is a modification). When I first was thinking about how to write the module `QNlalternative`, I wrote the particular case of `NN=5` in a sloppy manner, using repeated statements, as follows:

```
Q5l[l_, f_] := 
  Module[{s, wzl1, wzl2, wzl3, wzl4, wzl5, wl1, zl1, wl2, zl2, wl3, 
    zl3, wl4, zl4, wl5, zl5},
   s = 0;
   Do[
    wzl1 = weightsNodesQ1l[l1];
    wzl2 = weightsNodesQ1l[l2];
    wzl3 = weightsNodesQ1l[l3];
    wzl4 = weightsNodesQ1l[l4];
    wzl5 = weightsNodesQ1l[l5];
    wl1 = wzl1[[1, All]]; zl1 = wzl1[[2, All]];
    wl2 = wzl2[[1, All]]; zl2 = wzl2[[2, All]];
    wl3 = wzl3[[1, All]]; zl3 = wzl3[[2, All]];
    wl4 = wzl4[[1, All]]; zl4 = wzl4[[2, All]];
    wl5 = wzl5[[1, All]]; zl5 = wzl5[[2, All]];
    s = s +  Sum[f[zl1[[i1]], zl2[[i2]], zl3[[i3]], zl4[[i4]], zl5[[i5]]]*
        wl1[[i1]]*wl2[[i2]]*wl3[[i3]]*wl4[[i4]]*wl5[[i5]], {i1, 1, 
        2^l1 + 1}, {i2, 1, 2^l2 + 1}, {i3, 1, 2^l3 + 1}, {i4, 1, 
        2^l4 + 1}, {i5, 1, 2^l5 + 1}],
    {l1, 1, l + 5 - 1}, {l2, 1, l + 5 - 1 - l1}, {l3, 1, 
     l + 5 - 1 - l1 - l2}, {l4, 1, l + 5 - 1 - l1 - l2 - l3}, {l5, 1, 
     l + 5 - 1 - l1 - l2 - l3 - l4}
    ];
   Return[s]
   ];
```

The module `Q5l` is much faster than `QNlalternative`:

```
AbsoluteTiming[QNlalternative[5, 6, Sin[Plus[##]]^2 &]]
(* {19.4634, 6213.02} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Q5l[6, Sin[Plus[##]]^2 &]]
(* {6.64357, 6213.02} *)
```

Why is `QNlalternative` slower? Which step of the generalization of `Q5l` to an arbitrary `NN` is too slow?

Comment: Hm. I think the problem is that Mathematica cannot jit-compile the `Do` loop due to the presence of symbolic code (basically the `lvec` and `j` symbol)...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Is there any alternative way of writing `QNlalternative`?

Answer (score 1):

An important problem seems to be `Sum` with the `j` symbols. The following modification makes the code faster:

```
QNlalternative2[NN_, l_, f_] := Module[{s, wz, w, z, lvec},
   s = 0;
   Do[wz = Table[weightsNodesQ1l@lvec@i, {i, NN}];
      w = Table[wz[[i]][[1, All]], {i, NN}];
      z = Table[wz[[i]][[2, All]], {i, NN}];
      s = s + Total[
         Flatten[Function[Outer[f, ##]] @@ z, NN - 1]*
          Flatten[Function[Outer[Times, ##]] @@ w, NN - 1]], ##] & @@ 
    Table[{lvec[i], l + NN - 1 - Total@Table[lvec[k], {k, i - 1}]}, {i, NN}];
   Return[s]];
```

```
AbsoluteTiming[QNlalternative2[5, 6, Sin[Plus[##]]^2 &]]
(* {2.76423, 6213.02} *)
```

I do not know if there is an alternative for the `Do` loop. Other suggestions to speed up the code are welcome.

Edit: I found an alternative without the `Do` loop, but the timings are similar:

```
QNlalternative3[NN_, l_, f_] := Module[{wz, w, z, lvec},
   wz = Flatten[Table[weightsNodesQ1l@lvec@i, ##, {i, NN}] & @@ 
      Table[{lvec[i], l + NN - 1 - Total@Table[lvec[k], {k, i - 1}]}, {i, NN}], NN + 1];
   w = Partition[wz[[;; ;; 2]], NN];
   z = Partition[wz[[2 ;; ;; 2]], NN];
   Return@Total@Table[
      Total[Flatten[Function[Outer[f, ##]] @@ z[[v]], NN - 1]*
        Flatten[Function[Outer[Times, ##]] @@ w[[v]], NN - 1]], {v, Length[w]}];
   ];
```

```
AbsoluteTiming[QNlalternative3[5, 6, Sin[Plus[##]]^2 &]]
(* {2.73529, 6213.02} *)
```